# Multilevel Logistic Regression with categorical variables

Tags: r, logistic, multiple-regression

I want to explore the effect of time of a day on 4 different medicine types in a between group design. My data looks like:

| Medicine Type | Participant | Time of the day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | Between 9 am - 12 noon |
| First | 1 | Between 12 noon - 3 pm |
| First | 1 | Between 3 pm - 6 pm |
| First | 1 | Between 6 pm - 9 pm |
| First | 1 | Between 9 pm - 12am |
| .... | ... | ... |
| Fourth | 160 | Between 9 am - 12 noon |

I plan to analyze each row as one observation and perform multilevel logistic regression per category, predicting proportions of the 5 times of time of the day *separately*. So in such a model each row is one observation, with 5 rows per participant. With a random intercept per participant and a dependent measure that indicating whether this is between 9 am - 12 noon or not (and 4 more measures for the other 4 time of the day).

I use lmer for this:

`fit02 <- lmer (Time of the day ~ Medicine Type + (1 | Participant), data = MLM)`

where I coded each time of the day between 1 to 5, *i.e.,* Between 9 am - 12 noon as **1**, Between 12 noon - 3 pm as **2** and so on..

My output is:

```
REML criterion at convergence: 8069.5

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8486 -0.8998 -0.1661  0.7278  2.3438 

Random effects:
 Groups          Name        Variance
 Participant (Intercept) 0.1609  
 Residual                    1.5826  

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate
(Intercept)                2.31500
Second                    -0.23167
Third                      0.01833
Fourth                     0.08333
                          Std. Error
(Intercept)                  0.08162
Second                       0.11542
Third                        0.11542
Fourth                       0.11542
                          t value
(Intercept)                28.364
Second                     -2.007
Third                       0.159
Fourth                      0.722

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) MLM$CB MLM$CH
Second      -0.707              
Third       -0.707  0.500       
Fourth      -0.707  0.500  0.500
```

**Questions**:

a) Am I using the correct method to do the logistic regression? If yes, the effect of first medicine is not visible in lmer.

b) How can I showcase which medicine type was significantly different than other for a specific time of the day?

Comment: Just a quick note, your code does not match the r code for logistic regression. lmer assumes your outcome variable is continuous. If I understood correctly, you have recoded your dependent variable into several categorical binary variables (e.g. "9 to 12 vs. not") and intend to test each separately. In this case, you'd want glmer and family=binomial.                  fit02<-glmer(Time of the day_01 ~ Medicine type + (1|Participant), data=MLM, family=binomial)

Comment: Thanks! I understand. 2 questions: a) Would you suggest me to categorize time of the day and medicines as factors before doing GLMER? b) Is there a way I can predict the proportions for the time of the day?

Comment: a) if you use glmer function, and you put in a dependent variable with 2 levels, the function automatically assumes that the outcome is factorial (or categorical, in any case, the one you want). In the data snippet you post, your "Medicine" variable has levels specified as strings ("First", "Fourth") etc. If this is how the data is also read in R, R also automatically reads "Medicine" as factor. Your output also suggests that has happened in the model you tested. So, you don't have to specify these as factors. Just use glmer and you'll get what you need.

Comment: ...continued: If you want to use all Time of day levels in the same model, you can use multinomial logistic regression, see e.g. https://datasciencebeginners.com/2018/12/20/multinomial-logistic-regression-using-r/

Comment: b) unfortunately, I'm inexperienced in handling data with proportions, so I don't dare to comment on that, but I'm sure you can do that- hope someone will respond about that soon!

Comment: I managed to use the GLMER and got the desired result. However, I am still struggling with the proportions? Any links where I can read more about it. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to model. What do you mean by "the effect of time of a day on 4 different medicine types"?

Comment: I want to understand what is the effect of each medicine on different times of a day?